# Check Style, PMD, FindBugs in incremental builds

Tags: findbugs, checkstyle, pmd, incremental-build

I am planning to run check style on my project incrementally. Present my CI server is doing incremental builds, that is only running unit test for modified files and dependencies. But for check style, PMD, Findbugs we are running on whole project instead of only on modified files.

I need to run the these static analysis tools on whole project for first build and after that for every incremental build run on only modified set of files. And merge the results of the modified files to complete results that way I get to know whether tool validations count.

Is there any ant tasks available for the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether a straight forward option is available to solve your problem.
There is no way for the tools to dynamically identify only the modified files instead of executing the tool against full path given in the configurations (e.g: source path/binary path). Since you want to preserve the previous results this is bit complex.

First you need to find out whether there is a way to get the list of modified files at the time of incremental build execution. If that is possible, then you can modify ant target to copy only the modified files into a temp. location and point that to the tools.

Then to merge with the previous reports, 
First, you will have to back-up the existing reports before the execution of above ant-target.  Then write an xsl to replace the information in the existing report by the information contain in the new report. Create a separate report by executing [xsl using ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html). So that report will contain the results you need.

Comment: Actually, PMD itself support incremental analysis: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.4.0/pmd_userdocs_getting_started.html#incremental-analysis Results can be cached from run to run, and produce a full report without looking at unchanged filed.

Answer (score 0):

If your CI system can create the list of files that it considers changed (I assume it can, since it used such a list for compilation), then you should be able to achieve the result at least partially.

For CheckStyle and PMD, their ant tasks take filesets which give the files on which the analyses should run. Give them only the changed files.

FindBugs, at least [according to the documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html), can't do that. That makes sense, because there are many FindBugs detectors that read files other than the one checked in order to do their work. Thus, FindBugs analyses can yield different results for the same file depending on the other files available for analysis.

You will not get a consolidated report in the end. Instead, your reports from the tools will only include information on the files actually checked. This is probably enough to decide on whether to fail the build.

[If you want to do this on a larger scale, track the development of rules compliance, technical debt etc., I recommend the free [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) tool. SonarQube also integrates with your CI system. It will not do incremental runs, though. **Update:** Since SonarQube version 4.0, incremental analyses are possible. See [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-4-0-in-screenshots/) under "Incremental analysis".]

Comment: Actually, PMD itself support incremental analysis: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.4.0/pmd_userdocs_getting_started.html#incremental-analysis Results can be cached from run to run, and produce a full report without looking at unchanged filed.